# How to set twittertime the other way

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed

Someone wrote a twitter plugin for e107.
In the admin part there is a possibility to change the HTML template (use within each li element)

Now standard this is set to:

```
%text% <a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id%/">%time%</a>
```

My problem is that this generates a time in the timeline of:

My tweet bla bla bla
8:35 PM Nov 2nd

I would like to see this as:
My tweet bla bla bla
10 minutes ago (or 2 days ago, etc)

Is there another time code for this in stead of using %time% ?

Answer (score 0):

A tweak to the plugin would be needed to change the functionality of the %time%.

The niceTime function on the following link would be what you would want to include add... http://manas.tungare.name/software/twitter-php-script/